# Git Bash source command cannot find bashrc file when one exists

Tags: bash, sqlite, git-bash

I am a beginner just starting out and am trying to be able to use the Git Bash Shell for SQLite. I've searched around the forums and was able to create a .bashrc file in C:\Users\name. .bash_profile was also created when I restarted Git Bash.

The problem is that when I use the source ~./bashrc command in the terminal it says:

bash: ~./bashrc: No such file or directory

I was able to add an alias to the .bashrc file and this is all that is in the file:

alias sqlite3="winpty /c/Users/name/Downloads/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3390200/sqlite3.exe"

How do I fix this? I thought I had created the file in the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

The path is wrong. The file is usually called `.bashrc` and it lives under `~`, so it should be `~/.bashrc` (rather than `~./bashrc`).